# What are some easy ways to preform terrorist site taking executions on de_inferno?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've always found when playing Inferno in matchmaking my teammates and I never have enough synergy to take sites well, as it requires passing through choke points such as banana, apartments, or cross fires such as the top of middle.

What are some easy to perform executes I could teach solo queue players to perform when trying to IGL in matchmaking?

Comment: It's probably not worth it exploring this topic as they will most likely revamp the entire map so much so, that it would become a new map (Exactly like nuke)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest bomb site takings when in Solo-Queue is taking B once you have Banana control. All there is to it is that you, and one or two of your teammates know a good smoke (You will want to get Spools and CT for the most part here) or molly (same general locations to get the defenders to move), throw these + a good flash and the bomb-site is almost certainly guaranteed.

Another easy to achieve attack that doesn't require a 5 pre-made team is smoking one of the sides when attacking A from middle, and then Flash+proper peaking. From there, depending on which side you smoked, you can either sync with taking Apps, or go CT Spawn to B/Library an carry on the attacks.